# Save metadata information in .odt file in LibreOffice

Tags: java, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I have to save a property of type `String` in metadata of .odt file. I'm using `Java` but the documentation is very poor (the worst documentation I ever seen) and I have no idea how to set metadata programmatically.

I have an instance of the current document open in LibreOffice but I don't know how to save info in metadata.

Ideas ?

Comment: have you looked at [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html)? as far as i know, setting metadata is the same regardless of file type (although it is OS-specific). ODT files should be no exception.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you an example in StarBasic, working with LO 4.1

First code example is to read custom document properties

```
Sub readDocumentProperties

PROPS = ThisComponent.DocumentProperties

UDP = PROPS.getUserDefinedProperties()

PV = UDP.getPropertyValues()

For i = 0 to uBound(PV)
   onePV = PV(i)
   MsgBox "Name = " & onePV.Name & " Value = " & onePV.Value
Next

End Sub
```

And then for set a meta data "Pathname" with value "myString":

```
Sub setMetaString

PROPS = ThisComponent.DocumentProperties

UDP = PROPS.getUserDefinedProperties()

UDP.addProperty("Pathname",0,"myString")

End Sub
```

I admit I got this from the [Community forum](https://forum.openoffice.org/) not from some documentation.

HTH